# session_start() doesn't seem to work

Tags: php

I am writing a form that verifies a sign in according to a youtube tutorial: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mn0ucCuNOTI.

The thing is I can't make this particular page work:

```
    <?php include_once("db.php") 
     session_start();
     ?>

    <?php
$user = $_POST['name'];
$pass = $_POST['pwd'];

 $sql="SELECT count(*) from phplogin WHERE(username='$user' and password='$pass')";

$query = mysql_query($sql);

$result = mysql_fetch_array($query);

if($result[0] > 0) {
    $_SESSION['userName']=$user;
    echo "Succesful login!";

    echo "<br /> Welcome " .$_SESSION['userName']. "!";
    echo "<br /><a href='signupform.php' > SignUp </a>";
    echo "<br /><a href='signinform.php' > SignIn </a>";
    echo "<br /><a href='logout.php' > LogOut </a>";
}
else{
echo "Login failed!";
echo "<br /><a href='signupform.php' > SignUp </a>";
echo "<br /><a href='signinform.php' > SignIn </a>";

}
?>
```

The thing is when I removed start_session() the site worked (of course I haven't started to use the session for real). I don't know if the problem is in my code.

Now I get the following error message instead:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'session_start' (T_STRING) in C:\webserver\apache\htdocs\sign_in_up\signin.php on line 2

Comment: So you got the error at line 2 and you did not see it? :)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them#18092277

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're simply missing a semicolon after your `include_once` statement:

```
<?php
   include_once("db.php"); // Added the missing semi-colon
   session_start();
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
<?php include_once("db.php") ;//semi-colon was missing
     session_start();
     ?>
```

Comment: While this is the right answer, it would be nice if you included a one line explanation of what was wrong, rather than just 'try this'.

Comment: @xbonez  you're right. done :-)

Answer (score 2):

You have a missing semi-colon.

```
<?php include_once("db.php"); 
 session_start();
 ?>
```

PHP cannot process the next function correctly due to this missing syntax.. Hence the error showing on the next line.